Ethernet controller for raspberry circuit review
I am working on an electronic design that was previously completed by a third party. This designed board has a Raspberry Pi Zero 2W attached, an Ethernet controller module based on the ENC28J60, and an RJ45 connector. This Ethernet controller module is similar to the GeeekPi ENC28J60 Overlays HAT V1.02 board.
The issue is that the Raspberry Pi is unable to establish a network connection via Ethernet, as the ENC28J60 chip is not even recognized. I have checked the Raspberry Pi’s configuration, and it is correct and consistent with the chosen SPI pins. While reviewing the design, I noticed some things that caught my attention and differ from what is specified in the ENC28J60 datasheet. In the following photo, the most important issues are highlighted in red, and in orange, I have marked things I am unsure about regarding their functionality:

-The Bias resistor is 2K instead of 2.32K.
-A ferrite bead is missing.
-In the datasheet, the center tap of the RD+/- transformer is not powered by 3.3V.
-The chip’s OSC1 input is connected to OSCOUT and OSC2 to OSCIN.
I would appreciate it if you could help me determine whether these identified issues could be critical for its operation, or if I need to look for the problem elsewhere.
Thank you in advance.

How much is voltage on Vcap? The Rbias resistor value affects output amplitude and the ferrite bead is for passing EMI tests. They should not render the chip unresponsive. However, having the receive pair center tap and bias resistors might damage, but it should also tolerate 5V and it may be OK. Crystal net names are irrelevant, they are just names, and OSC2 is output. Does the crystal oscillate properly? Does the chip get 3.3v supply? Is it properly connected to correct RPi pins?

This third party that made the board - did they not write design documentation? If this is a professional setting I would expect them to support their delivery - free of charge.

Unfortunately, the third party cannot give any information. VCAP is 3.3V. RPI pins have been thoroughly analysed and they are okay. I've done measures with my multimeter and the ENC28J60 chip is getting proper supply.

In order
Critical I would change the bias resistor. The datasheet calls for 2.32k and gives no reason for using 2k, nor does it guarantee behaviour at different values.
The abscence of a bead wouldn't concern me here, though I would check the 3v3 line to see if it's noisy. You can see from the ENC28J60 datasheet, figure 2-4, there's a note 3) "These components are installed for EMC..."
Critical I can't see a sensible reason to pull the centre tap of TPIN+/- to 3v3. I would revert this to leaving it floating, and having the 49R9 resistors on TPIN+/- tied to a cap to GND as per the diagram.
The use of OSCIN and OSCOUT is a bit poor here, as the design is using a crystal. Crystals are symetrical and it doesn't matter which way round they are connected or used. It's common for devices to be able to operate using either a crystal or other clock source, such as a clock from another device, and this chip is the same. See datasheet page 5. Oddly, OSC1 is the input for a clock signal, so to name it OSCOUT is poor IMO as it could lead to a bug if the design is later changed. As is, while the naming is confusing it's not causing problems. 
I also notice the oscilator is marked as 16pf, but loaded with 20pf. It would be worth checking the speciffic part number and making sure it's loaded properly.

Why do you think the 16pF crystal should not have two 20pF caps to be loaded correctly? And while crystals are symmetrical, the chip isn't.

@Justme I would expect a crystal marked 16pF to be loaded with 16pF, or perhaps slightly less to account for parasitics and any capacitance from the chip. Without seeing a datasheet it's hard to say.
I agree with you regarding the crystal & chip symmetry, I'm not sure that contradicts anything in my answer, could you elaborate?

It is not loaded with 20pF, but two 20pF caps which add up to 10pF load, plus parasitics. So in that sense you are correct, it is not loaded with 16pF, but likely 12 to 15 pF.

I'd thought it meant 20pf (or whatever loading cap it wants) on each side of the crystal. It feels like I just learnt something.

You said there is 3.3V on Vcap pin.
If there is 3.3V on VCap pin, the chip is toasted and damaged, no worth trying further with this board that has been connected to 3.3V. The absolute maximum voltage on Vcap is 2.75V.
What likely damaged it are the receive pin biasing to 3.3V with the resitors and center tap. Unless it's something else.
You need to find a board that has never been powered before, modify it to fix the issues, and then power a board that has been modified. Preferably with a lab supply that lets you measure voltages and currents to prevent damage if there is something else that is a problem, such as chip soldered 180 degrees wrong.
If you have only one board, or you have already tried all boards by connecting them to RaspPi and they have all been powered up, this may be an important lesson for letting external party make an erroneous design without them being the ones that bring up a board successfully.
